# Name for point in a satellite's orbit around a planet when the satellite is furthest from the sun

Tags: orbit, terminology

When a satellite is orbiting a planet (which itself is orbiting the sun) there are periodic points when the satellite is closest to and farthest from the sun, once where it is interposed between the sun and the planet and next when the planet is interposed between it and the sun.

What are the names for these two points?

Comment: Have you tried looking this up yourself? These are very common terms and a little Googling should yield the correct answer very quickly.

Comment: @Phiteros I keep running into perihelion and aphelion, which are not correct. Every search I put into google returns this.

Comment: Ah, I see. The satellite is orbiting a planet which is orbiting the sun. I misunderstood what you were asking. I'm not sure if there is a term for those situations. The closest I can think of is a [conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(astronomy)).

Comment: I think you could call it opposition? Usually meant for planets tho.

Comment: I've deleted my answer, I have to agree it doesn't really work.

Comment: Thank you for doing research @uhoh! Search engines seem to fully fail on this topic.

Comment: Aphelion and perihelion in fact referes to the farthest and closest distance between the star and the planet system (i.e. center of masses of the planetary system), I think. Given that, probably that terminology can be applied to only the planet but also to the satellite too. Just a thougth...

Comment: @KaushikGhose do you have any thoughts on the question [Do astronomers have an established, systematic way for saying what does or doesn't orbit what? (e.g. “Mars orbits Earth”)](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/27837/7982) I'm looking for something "established, systematic" if possible.

Comment: @uhoh neat question! I made an attempt there, but it has no appeal to authority, just "common sense".

Comment: @KaushikGhose thank you! I had a hunch you could bring some helpful perspective.

Comment: Something like syzygy ?

Comment: As far as I know no such terms exist.  Nor would they really be useful from a distance to the sun perspective (the difference in distance is normally dwarfed by the distance to the sun).   From a geometry, rather than distance, perspective - As @Phiteros said - when the sun is behind the satellite, as seen from the planet we call it a conjunction (bad time to try to talk to the satellite as noise from the sun will impact communications).  When the satellite is blocked from the sun by the planet we call it eclipse.

Comment: @CarlosN eclipse or opposition?

Comment: @KaushikGhose - usually eclipse for a satellite orbiting a body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments by @phiteros and @carlos-n under the question, the closest terms seem to be **Conjunction** and **Opposition**. As described in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(astronomy)) these are meant for apparent positions as observed from a given location - like the Earth, and meant for planets and natural satellites, but the diagram suggests they can be shoe-horned for this purpose.

[image: Conjunction and Opposition as illustrated on Wikipedia]

Comment: do you mean *inferior conjunction?* Also, I've left another answer that addresses this term.

Answer (score 1):

There are some serious problems with the [OP's own answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/31373/12102), and so I think conjunction won't do for a satellite in Earth orbit, at least in LEO (where many/most of them are). While [Archimedes](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Archimedes#Quotes) could move the Earth with the proper fulcrum and a large lever, I'm not sure this can apply to the aforementioned "shoe-horn" as well.

There are two problems actually:

1. In the context of artificial satellites, the term "conjunction" is frequently used for a *three dimensional* event; a very close approach of the variety that might result in collision. Satellite conjunction detection and conjunction reports have to do with scenarios where two spacecraft may collide resulting in "end of mission" and a whole lot of brand new space junk.

To read more about this, see what the letter "C" stands for in Celestrak's [SOCRATES; Satellite Orbital Conjunction Reports Assessing Threatening Encounters in Space](https://celestrak.org/SOCRATES/) as well as the questions

- [Conjunction analysis for deep space missions](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/3067/12102)
- [Which two satellites had a 44% probability of collision at 2017-01-07 21:53 UTC?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19708/12102).

2. [Parallax!](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax) for satellites that are not in absurdly large distances from Earth, their apparent solar conjunction wanders all over the place depending on the location of the observer. Even in 2D, for satellites in LEO (the ISS for example) there's a ~140° difference between apparent solar conjunction as seen from one side of the Earth compared to as seen from the other. With a significantly inclined orbit, formulating the way that a definition can be worded based on apparent solar conjunction becomes even more difficult, as does *even trying to draw it correctly* in 3D.

Here's a sketch of the 2D problem for a 400 km altitude circular orbit lying in the plane of the ecliptic, showing that the effects of parallax are huge!

[image: parallax]

Comment: Hi @uhoh this is an interesting comment, and makes sense if you define this visually rather than geometrically. Two points 1. It's not clear if conjunction and opposition are defined visually (like syzygy) 2. While it is a critique of the answer, it does not propose an answer itself.

Comment: @KaushikGhose as far as 2. occasionally answer posts are used as space for extended, thoughtful, technical comments where the conventional comment function is insufficient. I've seen this allowed in several SE sites, on a case-by-case basis. Search SE sites for things like "extended comment" or "long comment" or similar(keep the quotes). I found ~40 in Physics SE, ~400 in Math SE, and a few in Space SE and Astronomy SE. As far as 1. The question asks for "the name" rather than a potential name or a name candidate. Your answer is unsourced, it looks like you've just made it up, then accepted.

Comment: @KaushikGhose So in place of Archimedes, let's go with Hippocrates and say "[desperate times call for desperate measures](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/desperate_times_call_for_desperate_measures). It's not a perfect fit, but *I think I can shoehorn it in*. If you can produce a source that shows that opposition is correct for an artificial spacecraft no matter the shape of the orbit, that's great! But take a Sun-synchronous orbit with say an ascending local time of 17:00 and a) try to draw that and the Sun on a 2D piece of paper and then b) make a "geometrical argument" and I think you'll...

Comment: @KaushikGhose ...see that terms like "conjunction" and "opposition" are completely unworkable, and that's why your answer is not correct, and why there isn't a word. It's a 2D answer in a 3D world.